# Clipping UIImageView if is moved out of CGRect

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to clip an UIImageView if it moves out of given rect.

The image is moving across the screen by setting the frame, but I need to clip it when it moves out of a given fixed rect (say (0,0,650,650)).

Comment: are you using varying rect for UIImageView? try with that fix rect size....

Comment: rect is of fixed size..
clipsToBounds doesn't work..

Comment: You want to clip image? if its size is greater than the ImageView size?.

Comment: Nope.. I need to clip image if it is moving out of a fixed CGRect..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the center of the image an a UIImageView set the content mode to "Aspect Fill" via IB. That will center it and crop off anything extra.

Or in code

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

or

Subclass UIView and in the drawRect method, adjust the rect and draw out the clipped image using `CGContextDrawImage (context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage).`

or

Use CALayers. You can adjust the 'contentsRect' of the imageView's layer:

```
CALayer* imageLayer = imageView.layer;
imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
CGRect rect;
if (inPortrait)
  rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0); // half size
else 
  rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // full size
imageLayer.contentsRect = rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the property `clipsToBounds` of `UIView` and setting it to `YES` as it says in [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) that

```
 Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver
```

**UPDATE**

See if this SO question helps you

[Proper use of UIRectClip to scale a UIImage down to icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405994/proper-use-of-uirectclip-to-scale-a-uiimage-down-to-icon-size)

Answer (score 0):

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Try this.